# Solving a difficult integral

Tags: calculus, integration, approximation, trigonometric-integrals, mathematica

I have been stuck on the following integral for some time:

$$
I = \int^{2 \pi}_0 \mathrm{d}\theta \frac{\cos \theta\left(x + \Delta\cos\theta\right)}{\sqrt{k +  \left(x + \Delta\cos\theta\right)^2}} \exp\left[-\frac{\left(x + \Delta\cos\theta\right)^2}{\alpha^2}\right],
$$
where $\Delta, k, \alpha \ll 1$ are small parameters. $x$ is another (small) coordinate that is later integrated over.

I have tried a few approaches:

- Substitution: $y = x + \Delta \cos \theta$ is the obvious one, but I couldn't find a good way to handle the introduction of $\sin \theta$.
- Using the fact that $\Delta$ is small parameter to drop the $\cos \theta$ terms. I don't like this because you basically drop all of the terms dependent on $\cos \theta$.
- Mathematica: no luck...
- I tried something along the lines of Laplace's method, but this came out to be zero, so I think I went wrong.
- I'm not sure how to tackle this as a contour integral, I tried and it was a mess.

Do you have any hints that might help?

EDIT: Would the integral be easier to approach if:
i.e. if:
$$
I = \int^{2 \pi}_0 \mathrm{d}\theta \frac{\cos p \theta\left(x + \Delta\cos\theta\right)}{\sqrt{k +  \left(x + \Delta\cos\theta\right)^2}} \exp\left[-\frac{\left(x + \Delta\cos\theta\right)^2}{\alpha^2}\right],
$$

Comment: Do you have example values for the constants in your integral?

Comment: $\Delta \sim 0.1$, $k \sim 0.01$, $\alpha \sim 0.1$. The variable $x$ can be positive and negative, but $|x| < 1$.

Comment: "Mathematica: no luck"  Why to you think there is a closed-form answer?

Comment: Mainly because I am not an expert with Mathematica so: (i) maybe I didn't ask the question in the optimal way, and (ii) I don't know how Mathematica attempts to solve the integral. I would also be happy with a well-approximated answer.

Comment: Here are a couple observations: If you drop $\Delta$, the integral becomes $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos\theta \cdot \text{constants} = 0$. If you drop $k$ you are left with the following integral: $$\pm 2\int_0^{\pi} d\theta \:\cos\theta \exp\left(-\frac{2x\Delta\cos\theta}{\alpha^2}\right)$$ by even odd properties across $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$. The $\pm$ depends on the size of $x$ relative to $\Delta$, so this integral will not be correct if $x$ integrates across $[-\Delta,\Delta]$ and its complement. And if you drop $\alpha$ the integrand becomes $0$

Comment: I see. it looks like it goes to zero in a few different limits. Would the situation be improved if the lone factor of $\cos \theta \to \cos p \theta$?
i.e. if the integral is:
$$
I = \int^{2 \pi}_0 \mathrm{d}\theta \frac{\cos p \theta\left(x + \Delta\cos\theta\right)}{\sqrt{k +  \left(x + \Delta\cos\theta\right)^2}} \exp\left[-\frac{\left(x + \Delta\cos\theta\right)^2}{\alpha^2}\right],
$$

Comment: Caution, $\Delta,\alpha\ll1$ but the argument of the exponential involves $\dfrac\Delta\alpha$.